# Why does the browser force revalidation when serving an initial document request?

Tags: google-chrome, http, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I do understand how `Cache-Control` header works. However, I noticed that **the browser treats the document request differently from other requests**. The document request here is **the first request that the browser makes** when the user types the domain on the address bar and hits enter.

I tested an HTML page with the response header as follows:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable
```

The header tells that the browser should cache the response for 1 year. **But in the case document request, both Chrome and Firefox will revalidate it anyway**. The evidence for it is the **304 response status**.

[image]

Here is the test URL: https://test-http-cache-2exijs7pxj7x.runkit.sh/

I can not find an official document for this behavior. So it would be nice if someone could explain **how the browser caches the document request** and **refers to an official document**.

Thanks in advance!

## Edit

The outcome mentioned above is the result of a **soft reload** (when the user hits the reload button or re-enters the same address). For navigation requests, the browser respects the Cache-Control and serves the response from the cache

Comment: can it be that your Dev Tools have disabled the cache? In general there is no guarantee I guess, that a simple header from the server will force the user agent to respect the header.

Comment: @d.k I did not disable the cache for sure. Added the test URL so you can play with it

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I guess so. I just want to know the exact behavior to deal with it.

Comment: @Duannx if you are using google chrome, is the 'disable cache' checkbox set in the network tab? It might be disabled by default, w/o your explicit intervention

Comment: @d.k Please see the updated image. I did not disable the cache. You can test it on your browser too.

Comment: I have no clue, honestly. But as an idea, are you sure that the header is present in the response? Exactly one time

Comment: I get 200 from cache in both Firefox and Chrome today (When I first saw that question a few days ago I had conflicting results between FF and Chrome)

Comment: @Kaiido I'm still getting 304 in Chrome but now I get 200 from the cache in Firefox. It makes me more confused now ^_^

Comment: Yes, kinda weird. FWIW today I still get the 200 from disk cache in Chrome's first visit.

Comment: To be sure, when you type in the address bar, are you already on that same page or in another page?

Comment: Looking even more closely at this question, the nuances @Kaiido and  Kevin Christopher Henry bring up in comments to my answer are not really asked by the OP. What you two are asking is related to Chrome only revalidating the top level resource on soft reloads (which users really don’t do) and using the cache for sub-resources (which the test url does not have) based on heuristics. Article explaining the reworking of how chrome handles reloads: https://blog.chromium.org/2017/01/reload-reloaded-faster-and-leaner-page_26.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc8246.html#the-immutable-cache-control-extension), the `immutable` extension to the `Cache-Control` header:

> Clients SHOULD NOT issue a conditional request during the response’s freshness lifetime (e.g., upon a reload) unless explicitly overridden by the user (e.g., a force reload).
>
> The immutable extension only applies during the freshness lifetime of the stored response. Stale responses SHOULD be revalidated as they normally would be in the absence of the immutable extension.

The freshness of a response is determined by its **age**, which in HTTP is the time elapsed since the response was generated. You can read more about [how a cache calculates the age](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#fresh_and_stale_based_on_age) on MDN, but it is essentially the difference between when the object was stored by the cache and it's `max-age` (or the value of an `Expires` header), which in your case is one year, so any cache following the spec, should not attempt a conditional request to validate the stored object.

I have confirmed on my Ubuntu laptop using Chrome and Firefox that Firefox will not issue a conditional validation request upon caching the response, but Chrome will. If you inspect the [**Browser compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#browser_compatibility) table on MDN for the `Cache-Control` header, you will see that **Chrome does not support the `immutable` extension, but Firefox does**.

In short, according to the spec, clients *should not* issue a conditional request to validate a cached object that included the `immutable` extension to a response's `Cache-Control` header while the object is still fresh.

Chrome is not honoring the `immutable` extension, and therefore issuing a conditional request in the form of an `If-None-Match` request header due to the `Etag` on the returned resource.

**Addendum**:

The comments to this answer add an additional question not readily apparent in the original question. Namely, why is Chrome validating a cached resource that is fresh when a user reloads the page, but not during navigation?

Chrome has decided to not support `immutable` because they seem to feel their heuristic at handling reloads is sufficient and [not worth the overhead](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41253661#comment85) of supporting another extension to `Cache-Control` with [little observed value](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41253661#comment71). It has been available to work on for years, but nobody has bothered.

In short, their heuristic will only validate a cached top level resource on reloads (which real end users really don't do), and use the cache for sub-resources. You can read about how Chrome revamped their heuristic in this article: https://blog.chromium.org/2017/01/reload-reloaded-faster-and-leaner-page_26.html

Note, the test URL provided in the question does not have any sub-resouces. Not only that, it appears to be serving plain text as `text/html` where `text/plain` might be more appropriate.

Comment: The question, though, is why does Chrome send a conditional request at all when the cached response is still fresh? The OP is asking why the browser behaves differently when you type the URL in the URL bar (which is behaving like a soft reload) versus following a link, say.

Comment: I’d rather the OP speak for themselves and bring up any nuances in the question/answer they see as relevant. However, to satisfy your curiosity Chrome may be performing the conditional request despite the freshness due to content negotiation and the lack of a `Vary` response header so the client can determine what request headers were used to determine the returned representation of the cached resource. Try using curl or removing the `Accept-Encoding` request headers to test this.

Comment: It could also be the other reason given in this answer and another answer: The weak `Etag` on the response. I would advise a healthy dose of testing by those controlling the origin server.

Comment: I second the comment by @KevinChristopherHenry I believe you are on the right track, but you're not quite yet at the end of the road. If you go to https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41253661 which is linked from the very compatibility table you linked to, you'll get more details about what Chrome is actually doing. Quite a long thread and I didn't read it all, but there seem to be 2 different cases: soft reload and other resource fetching. [1/2]

Comment: For soft reloads they do revalidate. And indeed, hitting the reload button will 304. However typing in the address bar from another page does hit the 200 from cache for me. Which does corroborate what's said in that issue, but not what's said in the question... (Typing in the address bar from the same page does hit 304 though, which is kinda expected I guess, since that would be a soft reload). [2/2]

Comment: The real question is whether OP is after performance or lightening server load (perhaps both)? If performance I would argue the end user sees no perceivable difference from a cache hit or 304 especially when we’re talking revalidation on soft reloads only (real users don’t do that). In terms of server load, if a 304 is causing you pains then your load is so high you can afford to scale. In terms of end of the road, we’re talking a priority 3 bug that the chromium team deems essentially a non issue. The OP has what they need at this point. This is the end of the road.

Comment: The question stands on its own, even without a clear motivation from the OP, they expected something to work in a certain way and it doesn't, the simple curiosity should be enough. Saying that Chrome doesn't follow the `immutable` specs might explain why sometimes they do revalidate, but that doesn't explain why other times they don't. That explanation is inside the bug report. A good answer would dig that up and explain clearly why they revalidate in *that* case, and when they don't. The status of the bug is irrelevant here, the information it contains is what matters.

Comment: The information it contains is that a fix is of little to no value and nobody cares. This whole issue is making a mountain out of a molehill. If it matters that much to you nobody is stopping you from posting your own answer now are they? Go get those SO points

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I probably mislead you somewhere. First there is no animosity at all in my comments, I'm only trying to get the best out of you and your answer, for the community. Your answer is almost *very* good. Once again I feel you're only at a few steps of getting the whole thing figured out and that's why I'm suggesting that you take these few steps. Of course it's your answer, you deal with it as you see fit, I'm just sorry to see it so close to be real good. Also I don't feel like writing my own because 90% of it would be based on your research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257279/discussion-between-kaiido-and-morganney).

Comment: Then edit it as you see fit. I share the sentiment on the bug ticket, this is trivial and the OP has what they need. I’ve already gotten what I personally wanted from the question. People should read the rfcs for http caching anyway for a deeper understanding, and not a SO answer.

Comment: Since two browsers behave differently then one of them is following the specs (Firefox?) and the other isn't. You could say that it's a bug in the other and you have the answer. Besides, I agree with the part in the blog that says that reload is often used when users experience an issue with the page. In that case, ignoring the immutable directive makes sense.

Comment: Plus, based on my interpretation of the immutable directive, FF is doing the right thing: using cached version should be used for soft reloads.

Comment: @SalmanA my personal opinion is that a clear signal which `immutable` provides is better than a heuristic, even if only to unite the web platform under one spec for developers, and Chrome should only fallback to their heuristic in the absence of `immutable`. I guess you could say that the browser wars are still very real and alive in a sense.

Comment: Thank you, morganney, for the excellent answer, and thanks to @kaiido for putting in the effort to enhance its completeness. I appreciate all of your efforts. Everything is clear for me now.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer. But @morganney, could you do me a favor and restructure it a bit? My question focuses on the soft reload behavior (I will edit it for more clarification) so please update your answer to focus on showing the difference between soft reload and navigation. The lack of support for the immutable extension should be a bonus bullet. Lastly, could you please add a link to explain your statement "real users don’t do soft reload". Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will still send a request to the server this is called a "conditional GET"

as you can see on the initial request there is a header on your request which is the "If-None-Match"

This header is used to perform conditional GET requests based on entity tags (ETags) assigned to the requested resource.

The browser sends the ETag it has for the resource, and if the resource on the server has the same ETag, the server responds with a 304 Not Modified status code. indicating that the browser should use its cached copy of the document. If the document has been modified, the server responds with the updated document.

This process is known as revalidation...

I was wondering if you expected something different from the browser?

even if your browser already has a cached-copy of the page, it will still need to check if the cached-copy it has is an updated one...

if you want to bypass the revalidation entirely then you can disable ETAG... (which is what I think is the main issue)

if it does still sends a revalidation request maybe do things like make sure that your response have a `Last-Modified` and `Expires` Headers (I think this is a fix, if still revalidating, maybe you can update the test site you have so I can do some more investigations)

I hope that helps...

Documentations that might help:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#fresh_and_stale_based_on_age
- https://web.dev/articles/http-cache#response-header-strategies

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm expecting that if the browser respects the Cache-Control header, it should not make revalidation requests at all and the page should be always served from the cache